# What is the difference between "could we" vs "could you"?

Tags: british-english, pronouns

> Sales clerk : Looking for anything in particular, sir?
>
> Harry : Yes, em, that necklace there, how much is it?
>
> Sales clerk : It's ￡270.
>
> Harry : Erm, all right, er, I'll have it.
>
> Sales clerk : Lovely! Would you like it... gift-wrapped?
>
> Harry : Yes, all right.
>
> Sales clerk : Lovely! Let me just pop it in the box. There!
>
> **Harry : Look, could we be quite quick?**
>
> Sales clerk : Certainly, sir！Ready in the flashest of flashes! There!
>
> Harry : That's great.
>
> Sales clerk : Not quite finished.
>
> Harry : Look I, I don't need a bag; I'll just put it in my pocket.
>
> Sales clerk : Oh, this isn't a bag, sir!
>
> Harry : Really?
>
> Sales clerk : This is so much more than a bag! Ooh!
>
> **Harry : Could we be quite quick, please!**
>
> Sales clerk : Prontissimo.

--

It's Lovely Actually clip.

Harry said to the sales clerk:

> "Look, could we be quite quick?"

In this part, I wonder why It's "**we**", not "**you**"?

Now the clerk was loitering over giving a ring to Harry.

Then shouldn't "we" be changed for "you"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could have been `could you`, but it shouldn't necessarily be that. Both are valid ways to make the same kind of request.

In this context, `could you` and `could we` have the same exact meaning. It's obvious the clerk is the one who needs to get the job done, therefore it doesn't matter which of `we` or `you` Harry uses, it's clear he's asking *her* to be quicker.

**On the social aspect of usage**:

Depends on the situation, `could we` can sometimes sound a bit more polite than `could you`, while in others it can sound mocking. It can sometimes encourage the other party to do something quicker/better by giving him/her a sense of partnership/cooperation, and other times it can backfire, like it might have in this case.

Comment: Seconding this, in social situations 'could you' might have the negative  connotation that you feel the other person is always late. You are singling him/her out. By including yourself in the 'we' you make it about both of you as opposed to the other person.

Comment: @Zessa, but based on your explanation, if I use *"we"* to express my dismay against the slowness of the sales staff ("oppose"), meaning the sales staff also oppose me which is strange. So, isn't *"could you"* is better since I'm the only one who was opposing against the staff?

Comment: @XPMai I believe Zessa meant, "By including yourself in the 'we' you **make it about both of you needing to be faster**, as opposed to **making it just about the other person needing to be faster**." Zessa didn't mean, **You're both opposed to the other person**. Saying "could you" is more accurate, but saying "could we" is more friendly/polite. :)

Comment: @Keiki Yes, that is exactly what I meant.